# Streaming Video from Android Device

Tags: android

How do I go about streaming video from an Android device to a server that will get the video and analyze it frame by frame? The video will be a live stream from the Android Device's camera.

Comment: Which part do you need help with?  Working with the camera?  Feeding it to the server?  Analyzing it?  What research have you done?  What applications/libraries are you going to use?  Are you going to code your own program?

Comment: Well first of all you must have to research by yourself.Many tutorials are available.Check out this one :) http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/